# Solve for 69 using only 1 9 9 2 in that order

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

You must use all the digits of $1 9 9 2$ in that order to come up with $69$ as the answer.
For example

$ - (1 + \sqrt {9})! + 92 = 68 $

but you must solve for $69$.

Comment: What mathematical operations can be used? You must specify this, otherwise the puzzle is ill-defined (e.g. I could just define an obscure operation whose effect on the numebrs 1, 9, 9, 2 directly gives 69).

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing which operations are allowed, I submit the following:

> $\left\lfloor{.1}^{-.9} * 9 - 2\right\rfloor = 69$

**UPDATE**

Another solution that doesn't use the floor function:

> $.1 * \sqrt{9}!! - \sqrt{\sqrt{9}}^2 = 69$

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a clean answer, so here's an unhygienic one, which may at least be entertaining:

In the olden days of Perl golf (the predecessor of the more general [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)), we used to abuse this neat trick you can do in two's-complement math: if you negate an integer and invert all the bits, you get the original number minus 1. So (even without overusing the trick, which is obviously all-powerful) you could do

> $-1 + \text{~}(-9) \times 9 - 2 = 69$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvREHXULtO11LLUtfo/38A)

(PS: it may be difficult to see why "~-x" would make for a shorter program than "x-1", but trust me, it quite often does. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $(x)_n:=x\times(x-1)\times...\times(x-n+1)$:

> $-1 \times \sqrt 9 + (9)_2$

Or we can use $\Gamma$ which (for positive integer operands) is the factorial shifted by one:

> $1 \times 9 + \frac {\Gamma (\sqrt 9 !)} 2$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what kind of puzzle but

> Rotating each $9$ for a $6$ gives
>
>  $1 + 6 + 62 = 69$

Similarly

> Rotating the whole number to present $2661$ gives
>
>  $2 + 6 + 61 = 69$
>
>  After all, the question does say *"come up with"*